# Why is EntLib looking in my source code App_Data directory for my database instead of in SQL Server's normal location?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from my MVC app using EntLib 5.0. Here's my connection string (for SQL Server 2008):

Server=local;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True

I'm getting this error:

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 
C:\dev\pestsApp_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with 
the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, 
or it is located on UNC share.
```

Why is EntLib looking in my source code directory instead of in the directory where my database is located (the default location)? Here is the actual location of my database:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

How do I make EntLib connect to that database?

Comment: I'm afraid the true answer - though I'll post it as a comment - is "because EntLib is a piece of cr*p".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config you'll have to put a  in the beginning of your Connectionstrings section.
If you don't, your application will inherit the connectionstrings that are defined in the root web.config by default.

So:

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <clear/>
     <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=local;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This issue is not related to EntLib 5.0.

Perhaps a typo?

C:\dev\pestsApp_Data\aspnetdb.mdf => C:\dev\pests\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf

And your application can access C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA? By default it could not.

Comment: I added <clear /> as the first line in the connectionStrings section, and the app is still using: 

data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

Comment: Type? C:\dev\pestsApp_Data\aspnetdb.mdf should become C:\dev\pests\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf ?

Comment: That's simply a typo on my part, as I edited the path for privacy's sake. The app still shouldn't be looking anywhere near that file. It's still using the wrong connection string. Any other ideas?

Comment: I also just changed the way I'm reading the connection string from the config file. That did the trick (although I had to make your change first). Looks like the wrong connection string was the first one in the connection strings collection. Thanks!